# Mediaelement.js control panel not resize on Ipad safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, mediaelement.js

I have a problem with the plugin. When you resize the screen for ipad safari in the control panel does not resize. In all other browsers all ok.
The problem occurs when more than one video on the page. If the video is one that everything is OK. control panel resize

Panel not resize :

[image: Panel not resize]

Init player :

[image: Init player]

```
$(".one-item video").each(function (i, item) {
  $(item).mediaelementplayer({
    videoWidth: "100%",
    videoHeight: height,
    alwaysShowControls: true,
    enableAutosize: false,
    features: ['playpause', 'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'tracks', 'volume', 'fullscreen', 'loop'],
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I make such a decision. The player mediaelement-and-player.js before the line 2662 Add method In any case, with setTimeout. Work on ipad

```
    t.globalBind('orientationchange', function(){
                setTimeout(function(){  
                    // Look at the value of window.orientation:
                    // alert('ok')
                    if ( !(t.isFullScreen || (mejs.MediaFeatures.hasTrueNativeFullScreen && document.webkitIsFullScreen)) ) {
                        t.setPlayerSize(t.width, t.height);
                    }
                    // always adjust controls
                    t.setControlsSize();
                },500);
            });
```